# windows rename command to rename file.a.b to file.b

Tags: windows-7, command-line, apache-http-server, rename

I have a few folders with hundreds of html files. The file name should have been .htm but it is .asp.htm and it does not run. **It is plain html file and there is no asp code.**

So, I tried to rename the files using **rename command**. I tried like this

```
rename *.asp.htm *.htm
```

But it does not work. After trying a few other combinations I believe rename or ren command can't change the double dot extension. The only change the last extension. So, if I try

```
rename *.asp.htm *.asp.htm
```

I thought nothing would be changed, but, the file name changes from file.asp.htm to file.asp.asp.htm

I hope someone would help me with this. Another thing is, can I force apache to run files with .asp.htm extension? Currently it can't run those files.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ren *.htm *.` will change all .asp.htm to just .asp

`for /f "delims=." %f in ('dir /b *.htm') do @ren "%~f.asp.htm" "%~f.htm"` will change all .asp.htm to just .htm

Comment: this is linux that is windows

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome, sakib! @saber: sakib added the Windows-7 tag and so I provided a Windows 7 command. It is *not* a Linux shell command. Type `for /?` in Windows to learn all its advanced options.

Comment: thanks , i guess this seems to appear as linux command but this is work. i have'nt scripting skills. can you teach me?

Comment: @saber: This is not the proper site for tutorials, but if you want to learn check out the command-line help (type any command and then /?), and also check out [this *great* site](http://ss64.com).

Answer (score 0):

with  [Total Commander](http://www.tusfiles.net/ep3tsc62ep0s) and  Servant Salamander tools try it.

or [Rename-File-Extensions](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/File-Management/Rename-File-Extensions.shtml)

with ??? **doesn't** solve this problem

```
rename *.php.htm *.htm

rename *.php.??? *.htm

rename *.php.??? *.php.htm

rename *.??? *.php

rename *.??? *.htm

rename *.php *.htm
```

Comment: I don't want to change it to .asp.asp, I want to make it .htm. This version doesn't work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: some kind of tools here that solve your problem in windows

Comment: Thanks, but I can do it with just two commands. That's faster.

Comment: scripting is good skill that we have to learnit