# rename command windows to rename *.a.b to *.b

Tags: windows-7, rename, prompt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [windows rename command to rename file.a.b to file.b](https://superuser.com/questions/496730/windows-rename-command-to-rename-file-a-b-to-file-b)

I have a few folders with hundreds of html files. The file name should have been .htm but it is .asp.htm and it does not run. **It is plain html file and there is no asp code.**

So, I tried to rename the files using **rename** command. I tried like this:

```
rename *.asp.htm *.htm
```

But it does not work. After trying a few other combinations I believe rename or ren command can't change the double dot extension. The only change the last extension. So, if I try:

```
rename *.asp.htm *.asp.htm
```

I thought nothing would be changed, but the file name changes from file.asp.htm to file.asp.asp.htm

I hope someone would help me with this. Another thing is: can I force apache to run files with .asp.htm extension?

Comment: This is not a programming question. SuperUser is a better venue.

Comment: Don't, this question will be migrated.

Comment: Sorry, But I already asked there. What should I do now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with two ren instances:

**`ren *.asp.htm *.`** (this will change the extension to .asp)

And after:

**`ren *.asp *.htm`**

Answer (score 0):

There are some file renaming softwares available for free. Try them. Some of them I'll suggest you is [BullRenameUtility](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php) and [Multi File Renamer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/multifilerename/)

Comment: I believe my problem can be solved with a single rename command. So, I don't really want to try them. Thanks anyway. They might come in handy in future.